# Numba/numPy multiple run speed difference / optimization

Tags: python, numpy, jit, numba

I'm seeing some peculiar performance using Numba and also looking to optimize the JIT loop further.

Init and generate some practically relevant data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import time
import numba

times =             np.arange(datetime(2000, 1, 1), datetime(2020, 2, 1), timedelta(minutes=10)).astype(np.datetime64)
tlen =              len(times)
A, Z =              np.array(['A', 'Z']).view('int32')
symbol_names =      np.random.randint(low=A, high=Z, size=1 * 7, dtype='int32').view(f'U{7}')
times =             np.concatenate([times] * 1)
names =             np.array([y for x in [[s] * tlen for s in symbol_names] for y in x])
open_column =       np.random.randint(low=40, high=60, size=len(times), dtype='uint32')
high_column =       np.random.randint(low=50, high=70, size=len(times), dtype='uint32')
low_column =        np.random.randint(low=30, high=50, size=len(times), dtype='uint32')
close_column =      np.random.randint(low=40, high=60, size=len(times), dtype='uint32')
df = pd.DataFrame({'open': open_column, 'high': high_column, 'low': low_column, 'close': close_column}, index=[names, times])
df.index = df.index.set_names(['Symbol', 'Date'])
df['entry'] = np.select( [df.open > df.open.shift(), False], (df.close, -1), np.nan)
df['exit'] =  df.close.where(df.high > df.open*1.33, np.nan)
```

Timing function:

```
def timing(f):
    def wrap(*args):
        time1 = time()
        ret = f(*args)
        time2 = time()
        print('{:s} function took {:.3f} s'.format(f.__name__, (time2-time1)))
        return ret
    return wrap
```

JIT compiled function:

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def entry_exit(arr, limit=0, stop=0, tbe=0):
    is_active = 0
    bars_held = 0
    limit_target = np.inf
    stop_target = -np.inf
    result = np.empty(arr.shape[0], dtype='float32')

    for n in range(arr.shape[0]):
        ret = 0
        if is_active == 1:
            bars_held += 1
            if arr[n][2] < stop_target:
                ret = stop_target
                is_active = 0
            elif arr[n][1] > limit_target:
                ret = limit_target
                is_active = 0
            elif bars_held >= tbe:
                ret = arr[n][3]
                is_active = 0
            elif arr[n][5] > 0:
                ret = arr[n][3]
                is_active = 0
        if is_active == 0:
            if arr[n][4] > 0:
                is_active = 1
                bars_held = 0
                if stop != 0:
                    stop_target = arr[n][3] * stop
                if limit != 0:
                    limit_target = arr[n][3] * limit
        result[n] = ret
    return result
```

Tests:

```
@timing
def run_one(arr):
    entry_exit(arr, limit=1.20, stop=0.50, tbe=5)

@timing
def run_ten(arr):
    for _ in range(10):
        entry_exit(arr, limit=1.20, stop=0.50, tbe=5)

arr = df[['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'entry', 'exit']].to_numpy()
run_one(arr)
run_ten(arr)
```

When running this in native Python, I get:

- run_one function took 0.680 s
- run_ten function took 5.816 s

Makes sense.

When I run the same in JIT, I get something entirely different:

- run_one function took 0.753 s
- run_ten function took 0.105 s

Why is this happening?
I'm also very interesting in knowing how to speed up the function further as the current speed gains while significant, are insufficient.

Comment: You can make use of `cache=True`. This caches the compiled function on your hdd. But initializing the cache may also take some time, but with more than one cached function it will be much faster than compiling a function each time you restart the interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numba.jit` will compile the function when it is first used. This makes the first execution of the function expensive, and subsequent ones much cheaper.

Your test presumably runs `run_one` - which calls `entry_exit` which numba compiles - and so is slow to compile, but then fast to run. Then it calls `run_ten`, but `entry_exit` has already been compiled, and so the compiled form is reused - so it is fast.

In summary I'd expect the break-down to be something like

```
run_one: 0.74s compile + 1 x 0.01s run
run_ten: no compile + 10 x 0.01s run
```

To check this you just need to ensure you call the function once (so that numba compiles it) before you begin testing its speed. Or you can set flags to tell numba to compile ahead of time.

All you need to do to verify this is to change the test script to be:

```
@timing
def run_one(arr):
    entry_exit(arr, limit=1.20, stop=0.50, tbe=5)

@timing
def run_ten(arr):
    for _ in range(10):
        entry_exit(arr, limit=1.20, stop=0.50, tbe=5)

arr = df[['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'entry', 'exit']].to_numpy()

# Run it once so that numba compiles it
entry_exit(arr, limit=1.20, stop=0.50, tbe=5)

# Use the compiled version
run_one(arr)
run_ten(arr)
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how to write it better besides using precompilation?

Comment: If my hypothesis is correct, then you're doing it right. You're just not accounting for the compilation time. If you don't want the once-per-run compilation overhead then numba might not be for you.  However, It looks like numba has some additional persistent cache options, but I've not used them. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/developer/caching.html